# How to override ValidateAudienceRestriction in SamlSecurityTokenAuthenticator

Tags: forms-authentication, wif, saml-2.0, asp.net-4.5, ws-federation

I'm using .Net 4.5, running ASP.net Service configured with an Identity provider. I would like to alter the AudienceUri validation algorithm to allow wildcards or configure it to ignore subdomains.

In this page: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.samlsecuritytokenauthenticator.allowedaudienceuris(v=vs.100).Aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.samlsecuritytokenauthenticator.allowedaudienceuris%28v=vs.100%29.Aspx)

it says in the remarks:

> Optionally, override the ValidateAudienceRestriction method to specify
>   the validation algorithm to use for the allowed URI.

I understand that I need to create a new class, inherit from SamlSecurityTokenAuthenticator and override the method. 
But I'm not sure how do I apply this override, I believe that I should instantiate the new class and assign it to a static member of some class, such as FederationAuthentication, but I couldn't find the appropriate class.

Can anybody please clarify how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this.

If the RP validation of the received security token fails due to audience:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException]: {"ID1032: At least one 'audienceUri' must be specified in the SamlSecurityTokenRequirement when the AudienceUriMode is set to 'Always' or 'BearerKeyOnly'. Either add the valid URI values to the AudienceUris property of SamlSecurityTokenRequirement,  or turn off checking by specifying an AudienceUriMode of 'Never' on the SamlSecurityTokenRequirement."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233079
    InnerException: null
    Message: "..."
    StackTrace: ..
    TargetSite: ..
}
```

This exception (and many others) can be handled in Application_Error, determine the exception using Server.GetLastError().

I noticed that:

```
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SecurityTokenReceived
```

Fired right before this exception is thrown. This callback has SecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs, which has the SessionToken, where you can find all the audienceUri(s).
You can implement the logics you need there and add the relevant AudienceUri to:

```
    FederatedAuthentication.ClaimsAuthorizationModule.FederationConfiguration.
IdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris
```

As I said this is just a workaround, if you got can pour more information for my original question that will be great :)

Thanks.